# Chrome: window.open opens new tab instead of new popup window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popupwindow

I have this snippet:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="option-link" data-url="https://www.google.com">CLICK ME</a>
```

**JS**

```
var popup = undefined;

// Option links toggle
$('.option-link').on('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).data('url');

    if (typeof url !== 'undefined' && url) {

        function __popup_open(link) {
            return window.open(
                link, 
                'same_window',
                'width = 940, height = 620, toolbar = 0, menubar = 0, location = 1, status = 1, scrollbars = 0, resizable = 0, left = 0, top = 0'
            );
        }


        if (typeof popup == 'undefined' || popup.closed) {

            popup = __popup_open(url);

        } else {

            popup.close();
            popup = __popup_open(url);
        }

        popup.focus();
    }

});
```

Running the script on old version of chrome from v58 (58.0.3029.110) backwards will give the right behaviour of opening a new popup window.

But after I updated my browser to v59 (59.0.3071.104), instead of opening a popup window, it opens a new browser tab.

Is this an issue from the browser itself? Or something in my code makes it not work same provided that the only change here is the browser version.

**PS**
Trying this snippet to mozilla works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome no longer likes `location=1` for opening popups.

Change it to `location=0` or `location=no` and you are good to go.

From the spec 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

location yes is used only in Opera.

Comment: Did you try this before suggesting it? Because it doesn't work in Chrome 63.